# Is there a way to use bincount with a clause in python?

Tags: python, numpy, sum, counting

I have hourly data about demand for bike rentals and weather. I would like to plot average demand for every hour, separately with good and bad weather.

When I plotted average demand at a given hour (without taking into account weather) what I did was compute total demand for rentals at a given hour and then divide by total number of hours:

```
hour_count = np.bincount(hour)
for i in range(number_of_observations):
    hour_sums[hour[i]] = hour_sums[hour[i]] + rentals[i]

av_rentals = [x/y for x,y in zip(hour_sums,hour_count)]
```

Now I would like to do the same, but separately for good weather and bad weather. The cumulative sum was easy, I just added an 'if' clause. I don't know what to do with counting hours of good and bad weather. I would prefer to avoid doing a big loop like with the sum... any function that does the same as bincount but with a clause? Something like:

```
good_weather_hour_count = np.bincount(hour, weather == 1 or weather == 2)
```

Any ideas?
PS. Perhaps someone knows how to sum rentals for a given hour without a loop? I tried something with 2d histogram, but it didn't work.

```
label_sums = np.histogram2d(hour, rentals, bins=24)[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`np.bincount` has a `weights` parameter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) which you can use to take a bincount of the hours *weighted by the number of rentals*. For example,

```
In [39]: np.bincount([1,2,3,1], weights=[20,10,40,10])
Out[39]: array([  0.,  30.,  10.,  40.])
```

Thus, you can replace the `for-loop`:

```
for i in range(number_of_observations):
    hour_sums[hour[i]] = hour_sums[hour[i]] + rentals[i]
```

with

```
hour_sums = np.bincount(hour, weights=rentals, minlength=24)
```

---

To handle good/bad weather, you could mask the `hour` and `rentals` data to select only that subset of the data which applies:

```
mask = (weather == w)
masked_hour = hour[mask]
masked_rentals = rentals[mask]
```

Then do the calculation on `masked_hour` and `masked_rentals`:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2016)
N = 2
hour = np.tile(np.arange(24), N)
rentals = np.random.randint(10, size=(len(hour),))
# say, weather=1 means good weather, 2 means bad weather
weather = np.random.randint(1, 3, size=(len(hour),))

average_rentals = dict()
for kind, w in zip(['good', 'bad', 'all'], [1, 2, None]):
    if w is None:
        mask = slice(None)
    else:
        mask = (weather == w)
    masked_hour = hour[mask]
    masked_rentals = rentals[mask]
    total_rentals = np.bincount(masked_hour, weights=masked_rentals, minlength=24) 
    total_hours = np.bincount(masked_hour, minlength=24)
    average_rentals[kind] = (total_rentals / total_hours)

for kind, result in average_rentals.items():
    print('\n{}: {}'.format(kind, result))
```

yields

```
bad: [ 4.   6.   2.   5.5  nan  4.   4.   8.   nan  3.   nan  2.5  4.   nan  9.
  nan  3.   5.5  8.   nan  8.   5.   9.   4. ]

good: [ 3.   nan  4.   nan  8.   4.   nan  7.   5.5  2.   4.   nan  nan  0.5  9.
  0.5  nan  nan  5.   7.   1.   7.   8.   0. ]

all: [ 3.5  6.   3.   5.5  8.   4.   4.   7.5  5.5  2.5  4.   2.5  4.   0.5  9.
  0.5  3.   5.5  6.5  7.   4.5  6.   8.5  2. ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Numpy, but you could do this fairly easily with the standard library:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

weather_counts = defaultdict(Counter)

times = [
    {'time': '1:00 AM', 'weather': 1},
    {'time': '2:00 AM', 'weather': 2},
    {'time': '5:00 PM', 'weather': 2},
    {'time': '3:00 AM', 'weather': 1},
    {'time': '1:00 AM', 'weather': 1},
]

rentals = [
    1,
    2,
    5,
    3,
    3,
]

for times, rental_count in zip(times, rentals):
    weather_counts[times['weather']][times['time']] += rental_count

import pprint; pprint.pprint(weather_counts)
```